# asp.net core execute with url

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebAPI project, where I have also implemented some API calls to external api services, which will then import and save to my local database.

Lets say, I have a route "/imports/mymethod", which will trigger the import run.

Now I want to make this as windows scheduled task so it runs for example every 10 minutes.

```
When I execute the "exe" file "myproject.exe" it says:

Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000"
```

Is it possible to compile my project and run the compiled exe file with parameters like "myproject.exe -path http://localhost:5000/imports/mymethod" then it will run the route with the method?

Or is there other way I can achieve this?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running this api just for study purpose on your local machine, following is the easiest option.
1) Extract the import logic behind the import route and call this logic using a console application and run this function every 10 minutes using a scheduled tasks. Important: Do this if only running on a local machine and if you are not actual planning to deploy this to production

IF you want to have this on production environment, then you have few options

1) You can write a webjob which is deployed with your web api and is triggered every 10 mins which will then import the data to your database. Refer [Run background tasks with WebJobs in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create). You can write the logic inside the webjob to import the data and insert into the database

2)Use a time triggered azure function to call the api from where you want to import the data into the database. This approach though sound adds another project that you will have to manaage

3) Create a timer triggered logic app which executes the same logic as azure function mentioned in 2

4) Actual expose your route as "/imports/mymethod" in you web api and then on your local machine create a powershell script or a batch file which invokes the web api and schedukle the powershell script or batch file to be run every 10 mins using windows scheduler

My personal preference is to use webjobs as webjobs were created specifically to run background tasks.